# Italy's SITA Bus tickets (Campania Region) buying process and questions

Tags: italy

I'm planning a trip to Italy to various places and one of them is the Amalfi Coast (Amalfi, Ravello, Conca dei Marini and Positano), which I'll get there by SITA bus from Salerno. While looking for how to buy tickets, I learned that they don't have e-tickets and have small shops, like cafes and newspaper stands, to sell bus tickets. The closet one I'll be in proximity to will be an actual bus ticket stand in Salerno. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

How reliable is buying tickets from these newspaper stands and such? If I'm uncomfortable buying it from those newspaper stands and cafes, can I buy those bus route tickets ahead of time? Also, is there anything I should know about SITA bus?

Comment: I don't know what you think about Cafes and newspaper shops there but why they shouldn't be reliable??

Answer (score 2):

All your assumptions about tickets resellers are true. I don't think you can buy bus tickets in advance as they are generic ride tickets (with time limit if I remember correctly) without assigned seat. Keep in mind that if the bus gets full you will have to wait for the next ride. With this said It will be relativel safe for you as you will take it from its departure place (not an intermediate stop)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start writing this by stating that SITA has become overcrowded in the last years. So, if you can take a ferry instead, that option is *always preferable*.

The Sorrento-Amalfi route is the busiest of them all. Salerno-Amalfi is much better.

Yes, it's safe to buy the tickets from newsletter stands, cafes, bars .etc.

A full list from where you can buy the tickets is here: https://www.sitasudtrasporti.it/agenzie (only in Italian...make sure you select 'Campania' if asked...SITA also operates routes in Puglia and Basilicata)

Check this link for what tickets you need:
https://www.ravello.com/sita-bus-schedule/#corsa-singola-ticket

Basically it depends on the departure and arrival town. For Salerno-Amalfi you need **AC3** which costs **€ 2.40**. The trip takes roughly **1 hour and 15 minutes**.

If you want to reach Positano from Salerno, keep in mind that you will need to change buses in Amalfi. Amalfi is the central transport hub on the Amalfi Coast. Same thing if you travel from Sorrento anywhere past Amalfi. You need a change of buses in Amalfi.

Other things to keep in mind:

- validate your ticket once you boarded the bus
- the buses have ample luggage storage
- when you wait for the bus in a station on the road, make sure you signal to the driver to stop
- the drivers are quite helpful, so if you don't know when your stop is up (all those curving
  roads will confuse you very fast), ask him nicely to announce it when
  you board the bus.

Answer (score 0):

For travelling on Sita bus from Naples to Amalfi coast, we found out the hard way today that you have to buy tickets from the designated shop. See photo attached. We could not buy the tickets on the bus, or at other tabbacci shops. The designated shop we found was opposite Napoli Garibaldi station, by the roundabout junction between Corso Arnaldo Lucci and Via Galileo Ferraris. We then alighted the bus to Agerola from the bus stop around 50 meters down Via Galileo Ferraris.

Posting here in case it helps future travellers!!

[Picture of ticket seller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xssk4.png)